# Automatic send mail with condition using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to create automatic sendmail to user that have a **stat** column with value still **668** in two days after created.
if before 2 day the stat column changes its value, then the user will not get the email.

I'm newbie in laravel, and don't know what code should I use. 
any ideas?
 thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? You could schedule a task to run and select all of the users that have that specific value in that column, then send an email. You'll need to keep track of the ones you've sent, though, so you don't send duplictes every time your worker runs.

Comment: Add the code with the checks for sending email. And add it to Cron. It will automatically test and run through the condition and send the mail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy to do it with Laravel, you juste have to define a task, follow this link for more explanations :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling